# How do I declare a sheet, not a worksheet, with "Option Explicit" enabled?

Tags: excel, vba

This subroutine is from a book. It only works when "option explicit" is not enabled:

```vb
Sub Test()
    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        MsgBox sheet.Name
    Next sheet
End Sub
```

How can I make it work with "Option Explicit" enabled?

Comment: What happens with Option Explicit? Is there an error message? What is it? Where does it occur? If you read about Option Explicit and its purpose, what then might be the problem?

Comment: @QHarr It is a compile error that says "Variable not defined".  It occurs for the sheet after the "For each". The problem is that we need to declare sheet in some way, but I do not know how to declare it...

Comment: Don't use `sheet` as a variable name, use something like `sht` instead. And then Add `Dim sht as Worksheet` after changing all the occurances of `sheet` to `sht`

Comment: @braX Yes that will work for my example, but are there not sheets that may not be worksheets?

Comment: Yes, charts can also be referred to as "sheets" - it's better to use `Worksheets` too...

Comment: @braX But then the code won't pick up the sheets that are not worksheets?

Comment: Despite the extra effort in using it at first, using `Option Explicit` is an *extremely* good idea. In the long run, it will save you debugging time. I would recommend forcing yourself to use it by enabling the `Require Variable Declarations` option under the `Options` tab in the VBA editor.

Comment: if you want it to pick up charts, then use sheets...

Comment: @braX Yes, and the problem is the declaration in that case. It seems that you can decalre something as worksheet, but not as sheet.

Comment: Use `Object` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Option Explicit` simply forces you to declare variables before you use them. In your example, the compiler would see that you are using a variable called `sheets` for your ForEach loop. Without an `Option Explicit`, the compiler will *implicitly* create a new variable for you of type `Variant`.

With an `Option Explicit` present, you will need to *explicitly* declare your variable before you can use it with your ForEach loop.

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim mySheet as Object

    For Each mySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        MsgBox mySheet.Name
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I run it I get the error "User-defined type not defined".

Comment: I see you changed "Dim mySheet as Sheet" to "Dim mySheet as Worksheet", the problem is that if we have a chart as a sheet we then get an error.

Comment: That's because the type `Sheet` isn't a vba type. If you want to be able to pick up both types of Worksheet and Chart, you would need to declare a variant. I don't believe there is a interface in vba that encompasses both Worksheet and Chart

Comment: Better yet, would be to declare it as an `Object` since it will be a reference type